tSQLt - How to fake/mock sequences
I'm creating various unit tests for our database using the tSQLt framework. Many of our stored procedures insert records into various tables. These procedures directly call our sequences to create IDs for the records to be inserted:
SET tID = NEXT VALUE dbo.TableName_SEQ

When creating a unit test for procedures that reference this sequence, I tried to use tSQLt.RemoveObject, but receive the error:

Object '[dbo].[TableName_SEQ]' cannot be renamed because the object participates in enforced dependencies.

As the procedure I'm testing uses this sequence directly, how should I handle this? Is there any type of tSQLt object that can fake the sequence like 'FakeFunction' and input the desired ID every time it's ran?

Please stop putting tags in the title; the tags go in the tags. See [ask], which explains that you don't need to put tags in the title

Please stop removing relevant info from my title and adding unnecessary chatter to this discussion. You are not helping this topic, only serving your own ego

It's not relevant; tags go in the tags, and you have the tag [[tag:tsqlt]] in your tags. "TSQLT - " does not belong in the title; we know the question is about TSQLT from the tags; that what tags are for. As stated in the article, [ask], that i linked before: "Don't include tags in the title. The system will automatically prepend the most important tag to your title for search-engine optimization purposes. You don't need to (and shouldn't) do it manually. If you want to include the name of the language/library/framework/tool, do it in regular English, not as a bracketed tag."

It's not a tag, it's relevant information for my issue that a tag does not accomplish. You're not doing anything worthwhile and you're upset you're not getting your way.

Can you elaborate how "TSQLT -" tells me something other than "This question is about TSQLT", which the usage of your tag [[tag:tsqlt]] tells me, please? If it does tell us something else, then the title does not make that clear; please improve your title, by using the [edit] to elaborate what "TSQLT" means other than "TSQLT".

At this point, there is not. Is the same issue as with indexed views that also use schema binding. I have started dealing with this in an automated fashion, but there is no ETA.
For now, you have two options. One is to break the schema binding manually. You can do that with the help of this statement:
SELECT 
   'ALTER TABLE dbo.mytable DROP CONSTRAINT '+QUOTENAME(DC.name)+';' [drop],
   'ALTER TABLE dbo.mytable '+
     'ADD '+
     CASE WHEN DC.is_system_named = 1 THEN '' ELSE 'CONSTRAINT '+QUOTENAME(DC.name)+' ' END+
     'DEFAULT '+DC.definition+' FOR '+QUOTENAME(C.name)+';' [recreate] 
 FROM sys.default_constraints DC
 JOIN sys.columns C
   ON DC.parent_object_id = C.object_id
  AND DC.parent_column_id = C.column_id
WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.mytable')
AND definition LIKE '%[[]dbo].[[]mytable_seq]%';

It will give you two statements that look like this:
ALTER TABLE dbo.mytable DROP CONSTRAINT [DF__mytable__id__42ACE4D4];    

and
ALTER TABLE dbo.mytable ADD DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[mytable_seq]) FOR [id];

or
ALTER TABLE dbo.mytable ADD CONSTRAINT [DF__mytable__id__42ACE4D4] DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[mytable_seq]) FOR [id];

(Whether you get the first or second re-create command depends on if the constraint was a named constraint originally.)
In your test you can now execute the drop statement. Then fake the table. Then use tSQLt.RemoveObject to remove the sequence. Now you can create your mock sequence (with the same name as the original). Finally, execute the re-create statement.
Now, you are ready to execute the code under test.
Word of caution: While tSQLt executes all tests in a transaction and, with that, will automatically put things back in place at the end of the test, this is not foolproof. I suggest inserting the drop and creating statements in some table. That way, you can get to them should the automatic ROLLBACK fail.

Now, that is the long way. There is an easier way: Option 2. However, this way is potentially not side-effect-free. It is the ALTER SEQUENCE statement:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.mytable;
IF(OBJECT_ID('dbo.mytable_seq')IS NOT NULL)DROP SEQUENCE dbo.mytable_seq;
GO
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.mytable_seq AS INT START WITH 100 CACHE 10;
CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable(id INT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.mytable_seq,col2 INT);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable DEFAULT VALUES;
GO
BEGIN TRAN;
GO
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.mytable_seq RESTART WITH 1;
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable;
GO
ROLLBACK;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable;

With this option, your test would look like this:
CREATE PROCEDURE mytests.[test inserts rows using NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.mytable_seq]
AS
BEGIN
  ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.mytable_seq RESTART WITH 1;
  EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable 'dbo.mytable', @Defaults = 0; --make sure the proc doesn't just rely on the constraint.
  EXEC dbo.myproc;
  SELECT id FROM dbo.mytable INTO #Actual;
  SELECT TOP(0) * FROM #Actual INTO #Expected;
  INSERT INTO #Expected VALUES(1),(2);
  EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable '#Expected','#Actual';
END;

In my limited testing, the rollback seems to put everything back in place, but according to the documentation, you might get gaps in the sequence. Also, should the ROLLBACK fail, it is going to be harder to get the system back into the original state.
That being said, you should not run tests in an environment that contains data you care about. If you follow that advice, I'd go the simpler route with option 2.
